# post and get data ajax just in own page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I totally have a website and would like to send information and data on the same page with PHP time I get the typical Is it possible to But I want it done via AJAX call, but the data output using Ajax entire page to be shown again, you please advise how to do this is possible and also the example below, a page is my ------->There is only one page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id_1');

    $.ajax({ 
        url:'new.php',
        type: "post",
        data:{id:id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        }

         });
    });
});
```

```
<div id="result"></div> 
<a href="#" id="button" id_1="20">test</a>
```

Comment: Your anchor structure with `id_1="20"` is strange. An element should get only one id and one or many class.

Comment: just check for ajax request and display content accordingly

Comment: what is the issue with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want the ajax results to be shown without the previous content, use

```
$('body').html(data);
```

instead of outputting the result in a div

Comment: I hope you are safe in God's grace in your life what you want it to be too early to say

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use separate php file to handle ajax calls.

But if you still want to use the same page you can check post variable in the beginning and not output other content

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])){
exit("your data");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you send a request to new.php, it'll basically output the same as if you had visited http://www.mysite.com/new.php

What you need to do is to handle this request and only output what you want it to output. So at the top of new.php, you add:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) // Or some post variable from the request
{
    /* Here you know you're handling the Ajax request */
    print "Response Data";
    exit;    // Stop execution of script here so rest of page won't be loaded
}
```